# eventlistner keypress not working as it should (stopping entire javascript from working )

Tags: javascript

i have a calculator project that works on button clicks , but i'm trying to add a feature where it takes values from keyboard press , i added a keypress eventlistener to first display an alert on key press but it stopped the entire project . please how can this be done .

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fpLdvw5k/)

```js
const a = document.querySelectorAll(".drum");
var y = a.length;
for (var count = 0; count < y; count++) {
  var z = a[count];
  var x = z.addEventListener("click", Action);
}

function Action(p) {
  var displayer = p.target.value;
  document.getElementById("screen").value;
  var msg = document.getElementById("screen").value;
  if (displayer === "AC") {
    document.getElementById("screen").value = "";
  } else if (displayer === "=") {
    document.getElementById("screen").value = eval(msg);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("screen").value += displayer
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keypress"
  nextAction);

function nextAction() {
  alert("use a button please ");
}
```

i'm trying to get the project to first display an alert when any key is pressed using the keypress eventlistener

Comment: Can you include the example in the question using Stack Snippet.

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular you should provide a [mcve] *in the question itself*. Providing a link to an external site and *some* of the code, but not enough to reproduce the problem, on SO doesn't meet SO's quality standards.

Comment: Your problem appears to be caused by a **typo** that applying a code formatter to your JS has highlighted. You have a missing comma between the two arguments you are trying to pass to `addEventListener`. There should have been a pretty obvious error message highlighting this.

Answer (score -1):

```
const a = document.querySelectorAll(".drum");  
    a.forEach(x =>{
        x.addEventListener("click", Action)
    })
    
    function Action(p) {
      var displayer = p.target.value; 
      var msg = document.getElementById("screen").value;
      
      if (displayer==="AC"){
        document.getElementById("screen").value ="";
      }
      
      else if(displayer==="="){
        document.getElementById("screen").value = eval(msg);
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById("screen").value +=displayer
      }
    
    }
    
    document.addEventListener("keypress", nextAction);
    
    function nextAction(p){
         alert("use a calculator button please ");
       
        document.getElementById("screen").addEventListener("focus", () => {
        
        document.getElementById("screen").value = "";
        document.getElementById("screen").blur();
    })
    }
```

**    here is updated code in which i made some changes and for the alert not getting displayed it was because you were missing "," document.addEventListener("keypress", nextAction)**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).